# Factorization of the polynomial $x^k + x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} + \cdots + x + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, factorization

Is anything known about the factorization of the polynomial $x^k + x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} + \cdots + x + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

When can it be factored, what are the irreducible factors, what are the degrees of the factors?...

Comment: You'll find a very precise answer (valid more generally in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$) in Demazure's "Cours d'algèbre", Proposition 9.17.